# Is there any way to store the value of std::string::iterator in a char * in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to store the value of `std::string::iterator` into a `char *`. How can I do it ?
e.g.

```
char* t_agent_val_c;

while (*itr != std::string::npos && *itr != '}')
{
    t_agent_val_c = itr.c_str();
    t_agent_val_c++;
    itr++;
}
```

Comment: Please ignore the c_str(), there. I did not mean it to be there. Posted it by mistake.

Comment: You may edit your post to remove `c_str()`.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. What do you mean by "store the value of `std::string::iterator`"? Do you mean the character it points to? Do you mean the abstract concept of the position it points to?

Comment: Is there any reason why `t_agent_val_c` cannot be a `std::string::iterator` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
t_agent_val_c = &*itr;
```

And `*itr != std::string::npos` is incorrect, should be `itr != my_string.end()`.